# What is a good first book on Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm planning to take a phd-level Algebra class this fall semester and so I want to spend some of the summer going through a good first book.  The phd course will assume knowledge of undergrad Algebra.

Is there something like a "baby Rudin" / gold-standard book for Algebra?

Is there also an easier book with both lots of exercises and solutions?

Thanks,

Comment: Dummit and Foote? Hungerford is not too bad either but focuses way too much on the category theory aspects.. which are a bit pointless for what he does in my opinion.

Comment: Oo -- is this classical and rigorous or easy and full of exercises (like a schaum's outline book)?  Thanks @cameronwilliams

Comment: seems like many people agree with you -- I will look it up now @cameronwilliams :)

Comment: I edited my comment. I forgot to hit enter.

Comment: Rigorous. Nothing like Schaum's.@User001

Comment: If you want a text with a lot of exercises that are easy, go for Gilbert and Gilbert I guess? That text feels like a first year text though.

Comment: I also agree that Dummit and Foote is a very good book. However, my favorite is "Algebra:Chapter 0" by Aluffi. It is more catogery-oriented (which is great if you want to study algebra or topology/geometry) and goes further than D&F. And it has lots of exercises of various difficulties.

Comment: @User001: This question has been asked many times on the site, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174596/good-problem-book-on-abstract-algebra?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413777/good-algebra-book-to-cover-these-topics?rq=1

Comment: Ok got it - thanks, @rise :)

Comment: Before you study abstract algebra, you should study elementary number theory for a semester or two cause its related to it. lots of proofs uses number theory.

Answer (score 1):

A First Course In Abstract Algebra-John B. Fraleigh, 7Ed would be very good.

Comment: This is more suitable for undergraduates than for graduate students.